# Remove core from Datastax Solr

Tags: cassandra, solr

I have a `Cassandra` table for which I have enabled `Solr` indexing, using command

`dsetool create_core <keyspace>.<table> [<option> ...]`

Question is how to delete this core?

I have tried `unload` via `HTTP Api` which returned `UNLOAD unsupported!`

Comment: Currently you have to drop the indexes in cqlsh. I expect this will change very soon though and we'll have a nice built in API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update,

unload_core is now avaliable as of DSE 4.8 -- [DSP-1533](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/RNdse.html?scroll=concept_dgf_wph_ts__48Chgs)

Verbatim from the [DataStax docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchUnloadCore.html)

> Unloading a Solr core To disable full text search on a core, unload
>   the core without removing its backing table.
>
> To simplify Solr code unloading, use dsetool unload_core. The syntax
>   of the command is:
>
> $ dsetool unload_core . [ ...] where 
>   is one or more of the following options:
>   Option    Settings    Default Description of default setting
>   deleteDataDir=    true or false   false   Retains the underlying Cassandra
>   data. deleteResources=    true or false   false   Retains the core
>   configuration and schema resources. distributed=  true or
>   false true    Deletes resources and data across the cluster. The
>   distributed option governs the removal of data and resources. The Solr
>   secondary indexes on the backing table are removed through Cassandra
>   schema propagation even if distributed=false. Note: If one or more
>   nodes fail to unload the core in distributed operations, an error
>   message indicates the failing node or nodes. Issue the unload again.

Answer (score 4):

Core unloading support exists in DSE 4.8, as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33393281/1810373) now mentions. For DSE 4.7 and older, you'll want to perform the following steps:

1. From `cqlsh`, remove all custom secondary indexes from the table that backs your Solr core.
2. (optional) From `cqlsh`, remove Solr resources for the core in question, like `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` from the table `solr_admin.solr_resources`.
3. (optional) Delete the contents of /solr.data/.

After performing step 1, no further indexing will occur on the node, and after performing steps 2 & 3 and restarting, there will be no trace of the core left.

Note: At the end of this process, the Cassandra table that backed your core should still be available.